# Android : Refresh GridView in Fragment

Tags: android

I'm sorry if my question seems common. I have google and have many results, but none of them I can apply.

I have a fragment that uses `GridView layout`. I also use `BaseAdapter` for my gridview.

When the data changes, I call `gridView.invalidateViews();` but gridview doesn't redraw with new data.

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                               getTable(position).setStatus("busy");   // change data 
                               gridView.invalidateViews(); // and redraw
                }
```

Or, I do another way:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.waiter_view_fragment, container, false);

    gridView = (GridView) (rootView).findViewById(R.id.waiterGridView);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapterHost(this, getActivity())); 
        // Add this line here
        ((BaseAdapter)gridView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

The answer still be same. My gridview doesn't redrawn, although when I test data, the data really changes, but dont update my gridview.

Please teach me how to redraw gridview fragment after  data change.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your adapter as a local variable inside Fragment, add a method to your Fragment that calls `my_adapter_variable.notifyDataSetChanged()`.
Once your data is changed find your fragment and call that method.  Something like this works for me:

```
public void gotLessonDetails(LessonDetailsEvent event)
{
[...]
    for (String tag: tabs) {
        StudentListFragment f = (StudentListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (f != null) {
            f.refreshAdapter();
        }
     }
[...]
}
```

Comment: Data change when item of grid view has been clicked. So, each time item has been clicked, I change data and I call `((BaseAdapter)gridView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();` inside its fragment. But nothing change :( Can I do that ?

Comment: Can you please assist? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40095826/how-to-update-a-fragment-that-has-a-gridview-populated-from-sqlite